# How can the EU collect money for the fines issued by the EU's Court of Justice?

Tags: european-union, poland, fines

[Poland was recently fined](https://www.dw.com/en/poland-pm-defiant-after-eu-imposes-large-fine-over-coal-mine/a-59245380) by The EU's Court of Justice for keeping the Turów coal mine open.

The same article mentions that the Polish Prime Minister would not comply with the order.

I am wondering how can the EU actually collect these fines. At individual level [there is a mechanism](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/cross-border-cases/judicial-cooperation/types-judicial-cooperation/payment-fines_en) (mutual recognition of fines), but I cannot find out anything at state level.

What happens if Poland refuses to pay these fines? Is there a mechanism for the court order to actually be applied despite the member country's refusal to comply with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Articles 29 & 31 of [Commission Decision C(2018) 5119](https://ec.europa.eu/transparency/documents-register/detail?ref=C(2018)5119&lang=en), with the catchy title of *Commission Decision on the internal procedure provisions for the recovery of amounts receivable arising from direct management and the recovery of fines, lump sums and penalty payments under the Treaties*, the fine amount (plus interest) can be recovered through deductions from EU payments due to the member state.

> *Article 29*
> *Recovery procedure and default interest applicable*
>
> 1. If  the  Member  State  upon  which  the  Court  of  Justice  has  imposed  a  lump  sum  or  penalty  payment  has  not  effected
>    payment  by  the  deadline  specified  in  the  letter  requesting
>    payment, the accounting officer shall immediately send a letter of
>    formal  notice,  asking  it  to  pay  the  amount  owed  within
>    fifteen  calendar  days,  plus  default  interest at the rate referred
>    to in Article 9.
> 2. If  payment  has  still  not  been  made  on
>    expiry  of  the  fifteen  calendar  days  following  receipt  of  the
>    letter  of  formal  notice  by  the  Member  State,  the  accounting
>    officer   shall  recover  the  amount  by  offsetting  in  accordance
>    with  the  procedure  set  out  in  Article 31 after having informed
>    the authorising officer responsible and having given  the indebted
>    Member State the opportunity to submit comments.

> *Article 31*
> *Offsetting*
> In  the  circumstances  provided  for  in
> Article  29(2),  the  total  amount  of  the  lump  sum  or  penalty
> payment  imposed  by  the  Court  of  Justice,  plus  interest,  shall
> be  deducted  from  payments due to the Member State.

In this specific case of the Turów coal mine, this procedure was alluded to by a European Commission spokesperson quoted by [Polish news website Interia.pl](https://wydarzenia.interia.pl/polska/news-kopalnia-turow-polska-nie-placi-kar-ke-pieniadze-zostana-pot,nId,5500221) (my translation):

> In practice, this is done through requests for payment from the
> Commission to the Member State. If the payment is not made (within the
> set deadline) and after allowing the Member State to provide
> explanations, the financial penalty should be recovered by deducting
> from payments due to the Member State in question.

Comment: And watch outgoing payments be withheld in return.

Comment: @Joshua, A situation which could easily escalate into *no* payments being made by either side. Not sure who comes out the better or worse for that. It's not just a financial issue, it's a perception issue.

Comment: @ouflak: Yes, that's what I was hinting at.